# What is the beginning nonce on the Rinkeby Testnet?

Tags: security, testnets, rinkeby, nonce

I know that the nonce is representative of how many transfers an account has made and is 0 at the start on the mainnet. However, on testnets, such as the now decommissioned Morden where it was 2^20 I believe, the beginning nonce is different. Right now I am working with the Rinkeby Testnet, however I am having issues setting the nonce correctly. Does anyone know what the beginning nonce on Rinkeby is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days the 0x100000 starting nonce for TestNets is no longer a practice as far as i know, as transactions now include a "chainId" which specifies if the network where the transaction is supposed to be executed on ( so reply execution is not an issue anymore ).

Thus the answer to your question is:

- account nonces start from 0
- contract nonces start from 1